# Image upload using react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I am new to react-admin. I am using react-admin to upload the file. I have following the step mentioned below [in tutorial](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload).

But after I submit the request...I see http trace as follow. I see blob link instead of Base64 image payload.

```
{
    "pictures": {
        "rawFile": {
            "preview": "blob:http://127.0.0.1:3000/fedcd180-cdc4-44df-b8c9-5c7196788dc6"
        },
        "src": "blob:http://127.0.0.1:3000/fedcd180-cdc4-44df-b8c9-5c7196788dc6",
        "title": "Android_robot.png"
    }
}
```

Can someone please advice how to get base64 image payload instead of link?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you have this handler, most likely you did not change the name of the resource `posts` to your:

```
const addUploadCapabilities = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'UPDATE' && resource === 'posts') {
```

Comment: Yes, as @MaxAlex said, this can be route problem. You did not notice that example code in documentation is enabled only for 'posts' resources of type 'UPDATE'. Just change condition based on your actual setup.

Answer (score 2):

Create your custom dataProvider to convert picture to base64

```
import restServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
const servicesHost = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

const dataProvider = restServerProvider(servicesHost);

const myDataProfider = {
    ...dataProvider,
    create: (resource, params) => {        
        if (resource !== 'your-route' || !params.data.pictures) {
            // fallback to the default implementation
            return dataProvider.create(resource, params);
        }            
       
        const myFile = params.data.pictures;
          if ( !myFile.rawFile instanceof File ){
              return Promise.reject('Error: Not a file...'); // Didn't test this...
          }

          return Promise.resolve( convertFileToBase64(myFile) )
              .then( (picture64) => ({
                  src: picture64,
                  title: `${myFile.title}`
              }))
              .then( transformedMyFile => dataProvider.create(resource, {
                  ...params,
                  data: {
                      ...params.data,
                      myFile: transformedMyFile
                  }
              }));
    }
};
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
  
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });

export default myDataProfider;
```

And get image data at your Server API

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {  
    if(req.body.myFile){
    var file = req.body.myFile;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data = file.src.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile(`upload/${file.title}`, buf, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!');
    });
}};
```